# Pagination is not working properly in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am currently using wordpress in creating my websites. And i really find a problem regarding pagination. So basically to be able for you to understand what is really my problem, I will post two codes:

This is the first code:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>             

<div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">                    

<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>        

<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH.'/inc/meta.php'); ?>                            

<div class="entry">                                                         
<?php                                                                       
  the_excerpt();                                                            
?>                                                                          
</div>                                                                      
  <br/><br/>                                                                
  <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Read More...</a></h3>               
</div>                                                                      
<?php                                                                       
  endwhile;                                                                 
?>                                                                          

<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' ); ?>                          

<?php else : ?>                                                             

<h2>Not Found</h2>                                                          

<?php endif; ?>
```

In this lines of code, I used the regular loop in querying a post. Actually I did not modify the code. I also installed a plugin WP-PageNavi. There is no problem, pagination is working properly.

But when i put this line of code, about the regular loop. Pagination is not working properly. I put this line of code "   " because I want only to show post in this said category.

2nd code:

**Line of code**

```
<?php query_posts('cat=8'); ?>
```

**End line of code**

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>
<div class="entry">
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Read More...</a></h3>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>
<h2>Not Found</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

My question is: What should I do in order for the pagination to worked properly? I really need some help with this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the because of the two The Loop(i.e while and endwhile loop) in a page.

instead of while use foreach loop. below is the example

```
<?php  
$args = array('category'        => '8');

$postArr = get_posts($args);

if($postArr){
    foreach($postArr as $details){
?>
div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php echo $details->ID; ?>">

<h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($details->ID;) ?>"><?php echo $details->post_title; ?></a></h2>

<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>

<div class="entry">
<?php echo $details->post_excerpt(); ?>
</div>


<br/><br/>
<h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($details->ID;) ?>">Read More...</a></h3>



</div>  
<?php
    }
}else{
?>
<h2>Not Found</h2>

<?php
}
?>
```

Note Code not tested...